# JQuery - disable inputs that haven't been added yet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable inputs with a particular class, however I want to do this for any future inputs added to the page.

live() and delegate() can bind to events on elements that don't exist yet. Is there some sort of selector that can run some code on future elements in the same way?

Comment: Do you add input elements via jquery to your page by clicking a link or something like that?

Comment: I can see where you are going with this. There are a number of events on various pages that might load new input elements. I'm trying to avoid adding code to every one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to build your own [custom event](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#example-6) and bind it to your document. So every time you create an input you cann call your event. With your own event you are free to add the disabled attribute to all elements with your specific class.

With custom jQuery event you can add extremly complex behaviors to your document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this means that instead of being able to listen for the addition of an input with a class X, I have to listen for events which might add an input with a class X. I was hoping for the simpler option but it looks like there's no document event fired when new elements get added

Comment: You are right... and also there is no event the browser fires when new elements where added to the document. Here is an overview about jQuery events: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: It's occurred to me that it should be possible to either wrapper or extend any jquery method that adds elements to a page (before, append, html, etc) to trigger a custom event that can be bound to. This will allow me to check for inputs and disable them accordingly. Thanks